# Python ASCII Graph Drawing

Tags: python, graph, ascii

I'm looking for a library to draw ASCII graphs (for use in a console) with Python. The graph is quite simple: it's only a flow chart for pipelines.

I saw NetworkX and igraph, but didn't see a way to output to ascii.

Do you have experience in this?

Thanks a lot!

Patrick

EDIT 1:
I actually found a library doing what I need, but it's in perl [Graph::Easy](http://bloodgate.com/perl/graph/manual/output.html) . I could call the code from python but I don't like the idea too much... still looking for a python solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say 'simple network graph in ascii', do you mean something like this?

```
.===.   .===.   .===.   .===.
| a |---| b |---| c |---| d |
'==='   '==='   '---'   '==='
```

I suspect there are probably better ways to display whatever information it is that you have than to try and draw it on the console. If it's just a pipeline, why not just print out:

```
a-b-c-d
```

If you're sure this is the route, one thing you could try would be to generate a decent graph using [Matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net) and then post the contents to one of [the many image-to-ascii converters](https://www.ohloh.net/tags/ascii/python) you can find on the web.

Comment: The graph may include forks and joins (the pipeline flow can fork and then join again). Therefore a graphical representation of what's going on would be nice.

Comment: Fundamentally, I think you'd be better served trying to output the data to file and then processing it using another tool like Willi suggested rather than trying to draw on a console. Maybe you could output the dot format required for graphviz and connect the console output to something which watches for the dot sections to draw your graphs?

Comment: Yes, I think I will go for such a solution.

Answer (score 4):

[ascii-plotter](http://www.algorithm.co.il/blogs/index.php/ascii-plotter/) might do what you want...

Comment: Different type of graph.

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly Python based, but you should take a look into the artist-mode of emacs

- [artist-mode video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDbi56U5qRw)
- [artist-mode site](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~tab/artist/)

You can control emacs from python with [pymacs](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~tab/artist/), or you can take a look at the lisp code and draw some inspiration.

Comment: This actually does something similar I'm looking for. But I would like to be independent from emacs or any other IDE. And I prefer to not write my own graph drawing library if I it's somehow possible.