# Generate terminal graphics

Tags: terminal

which open source software options exist for generating terminal graphics? I mean, there is for instance the nice matplotlib, which can generate beautiful plots from data, in PNG or similar formats. But there are similar alternatives for generating just kind of ascii graphics?

Thanks

Comment: Previously, on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/834395/python-ascii-graph-drawing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AAlib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/) and [libcaca](http://caca.zoy.org/wiki/libcaca) can both be used to render images in character cells.